# What does "liberty of interest" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> On May 12, 2015, Wallace, who was housed at the David Wade
> Correctional Center, initiated the two-step administrative remedy
> procedure (ARP) arguing that the no-smoking policy at the Correctional
> Center violated his rights of equal protection, freedom of religion,
> free speech, and freedom of association. On June 23, 2015, Wallace's
> ARP claim was denied on the grounds that "as an incarcerated offender,
> [Wallace was] subject to the rules, regulations, policies, and
> procedures of the Louisiana Department of Corrections ... [s]moking is
> not a right nor is it a **liberty of interest**."

Is it equivalent to a "freedom to do things that are beneficial to him"?

Answer (score 1):

I think it means that the liberty to smoke was not *of interest* (that is, it was not important to) the entity making the decision.